# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception while solving N Queens

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, backtracking

I am working on code that uses recursive backtracking to solve the 8 queens problem(placing n chess queens on an n × n board so that none of the queens attack each other).

My task was to create two methods:
Write a public solveQueens(int n) method to solve the problem for an nxn board

Write a private recursive `placeQueen(board, column)` method to attempt to place a queen in the specified column.

So far I have written this in my program:

```
public class Queen {

    public static boolean isLegal(int[] board, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (board[i] == board[n]) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((board[i] - board[n]) == (n - i)) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((board[n] - board[i]) == (n - i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    public static void solver(int n) {
        int[] board = new int[n];
        PlaceQueen(board, 0);
    }

    private static int[] PlaceQueen(int[] board, int column) {
        int n = board.length;
        if (column == n); else {
            for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
                board[column] = row;
                if (isLegal(board, column)) {
                    PlaceQueen(board, column + 1);
                }

            }
        }
        return (board);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        solver(n);
    }
}
```

My program successfully compiles, but whenever I try to run it, I get this error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at Queen.main(Queen.java:39)

Any suggestions on feedback on where I should edit my code to get rid of this Exception?

Comment: How do you run your program? Seems like you're not passing any program arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you provide a argument to the program ? 
It expects to have a `integer` argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       solver(n);           
    }
```

If you try to access to an index which is not in the range of the `args` array, it rises `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Is there a different way that you would recommend testing this by using a main method?

Comment: How to you run your class ? If you run in command line, you can do `java Queen  8` if you want to value your board array with the `8` value when the program starts. If your board should always have as size `8` , you should not use parameter when you create it but you should rather use a constant when you instantiate the board.